# Accessing element by class that called the method bind with onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this html code :

```
<div id="jiraTicketAccordion">
 <div>
   <h3><a href="#">key</a></h3>
   <div>
     <form>
        <div id="jiraTable">
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td class="label"><label for="arrival">ARRIVAL :</label></td>

           <td><input type="text" name="arrival" class="arrival"  
                     onblur="checkTime(this.value);"/></td>

           <td class="label"><label for="newarrival">NEW ARRIVAL :</label></td>

          <td><input type="text" name="newarrival" class="arrival"  
                     onblur="checkTime(this.value);"/></td>

        </tr>
      </table>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of accordion div -->
```

As you can see I have javascript function `checkTime` for `onblur()` event in that input box.

Earlier I had that text box with a unique id so I used `document.getElementById` for accessing it in my javascript function.

But now as there are many of accordion with same structure so I don't want to use unique ids for as there can be a large number.

So now I have a class for all those text boxes that require that validation.

But now I have to change my javascript functions where ever I used `document.getElementById`.

I know we can select elements by class in jquery, I also tried that but didn't get required results.

This is what I have tried in jquery:

```
function checkTime(dateTime){
    alert("inside  check time");
    var errorMsg="";
    regex = /^(\d{2})\/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M$/;
    if(dateTime != ''){
    if(!regex.test(dateTime)){
             errorMsg = "Please enter date and time in the format: \n dd/MMM/YY HH:MM AM/PM";
         alert(errorMsg);   
    //how to make the element that called this function to 
    //blank value it it failed validation
    }
     }
}
```

I wanted to access the element that called this method, so that I can manipulate that text box value.
And also I want to access other element by class in same accordion within that `checkDate` function.

I don't know how to make the text box vaalue to blank it it failed validation.

Earlier when I was having id ,I was doing it as :

```
document.getElementById('arrival').value='';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortest path from your current code is just passing the element instead of the value:

```
onblur="checkTime(this);"
```

Then on your function:

```
function checkTime(el){
    var dateTime = el.value;
    // rest of function
}
```

Personally, I'd avoid using inline event handlers like `onblur="..."`, and use `addEventListener` to bind the handlers directly from JavaScript. That would be one step further towards decoupling logic, structure and presentation.

Comment: but what about accessing other element say I want to access the element `newarrival` jsut next to the one that called this method, then?

Comment: If you have multiple of them as you say in the question, use `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')`, or `document.querySelectorAll('.classname')` to select by class. You may need fallback for old browsers that do not support any of those.

Comment: @Abu Also, if you're not using jQuery, it would be useful to create a custom set of functions to traverse the DOM, select nodes etc. Otherwise you'll end up with `for` loops everywhere.

Comment: can I access `el` using jquery `$` selector to find closest elements?

Comment: @Abu Yes, with `$(el).closest('selector')`

Comment: I tried this `alert($(el).closest('.arrival').attr('name'));` it gives undefined

Comment: The selector to `closest` must be an ancestor. You're looking for this: `alert($(el).closest('table').find('.arrival').attr('name'));`

Comment: finally solved it with `$(el).parents('tr').find('.newarrival').val(dateTime);`  THANKS !